# How to convert date string with GMT and Time Zone, to Date

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter

I cant seem to convert this date string

> Thu Aug 20 2020 13:50:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)

to a Date object. I am using AFDateHelper.swift extension and I am using this block of code to try and parse it.

```
if let convertedDate = Date(fromString: dateString, format: .custom("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz"), locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")) {
            return convertedDate
}
```

It doesn't go in the condition.

I have also tried using https://nsdateformatter.com/ to check if I am using the correct date format. And this is what it gave me. [image]

What am I missing on?

Answer (score 0):

Change your date format:

```
        let dateString = "Thu Aug 20 2020 13:50:00 GMT+0800"
        let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
        dateFormater.dateFormat = "EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzzz"
        let date = dateFormater.date(from: dateString)
```

and here is output:

```
Printing description of date:
▿ Optional<Date>
  ▿ some : 2020-08-20 05:50:00 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 619595400.0
```